# Prevent GROUP_CONCAT from returning empty string when grouped results are null in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have a SPARQL query that is returning what I want, save one thing.  When I use `GROUP_CONCAT` I receive back an empty string in the result.  I would like it to simply be `null` in the return set when the values getting grouped are `null`.  You can see in my example below my `?team` results return `""` instead of simply `null` like `?end` is returning.  In the case of the empty string, my `?person` values are actually `null`.  Is there a way I can get `?team` to return `null` as well?

SPARQL Query:

```
SELECT ?event ?start ?end ?team {
    SELECT ?event ?start ?end (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?person;SEPARATOR=",") AS ?team) {
        ?event a cls:Event ;
            prop:startDate ?start .

        OPTIONAL {
            ?event prop:endDate ?end .
            ?event prop:teamMember ?person .
        }

        FILTER (?start >= "2020-05-25" && ?start < "2020-08-31")
    } GROUP BY ?event ?start ?end
} ORDER BY ?start
```

Results:

```
| event       | start      | end        | team                                                         |
|-------------|------------|------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|
| event:Test1 | 2020-05-27 |            | ""                                                           |
| event:Test3 | 2020-05-28 | 2020-05-29 | "http://foo.bar/person/smith,http://foo.bar/person/williams" |
| event:Test2 | 2020-05-29 |            | ""                                                           |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid the SPARQL specification (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggGroupConcat)) confirms what you observe as the right behaviour.

To see why this is the case, imagine that instead of doing a GROUP_CONCAT, you were doing a COUNT. Then you if a team has no members, you would want to see 0, not null.

In order to get what you want, I'd try this as a first iteration:

```
SELECT ?event ?start ?end ?team {

    BIND(IF(?team_temp = "", ?team_temp, ?unboundVariable) AS ?team)
#The above check if ?team_temp = "". If it is not, then there is a team and you use ?team-temp as ?team. Otherwise, if ?team_temp = "", you use some unbound variable as ?team, and this unbound variable will be null.

    {SELECT ?event ?start ?end (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?person;SEPARATOR=",") AS ?team_temp) {
            ?event a cls:Event ;
                prop:startDate ?start .

            OPTIONAL { ?event prop:endDate ?end }
            OPTIONAL { ?event prop:teamMember ?person }
#Notice that if we want to match ?end and ?person optionally AND independently, then we need two optional statements above here, instead of one large one.

            FILTER (?start >= "2020-05-25" && ?start < "2020-08-31")
        } GROUP BY ?event ?start ?end}
    } ORDER BY ?start
```

Comment: that query can't be correct. What do you think `BIND(IF(BOUND(?person), ?team-temp, ?person) AS ?team)` does? I mean, it's outside of the subquery and the subquery itself does never propagate `?person` variable to the outer query.

Comment: also, the syntax itself is illegal. subquery has to be wrapped in `{ }` and you can't use a dash `-` in a variable name.

Comment: I should avoid using `BIND` in the body of the outer select - better to place the `IF` expression directly into the projection. ... also either change the condition from `=` to `!=` or swap the arguments of the `IF` to get the desired solutons e.g. `(IF(?team_temp = "", $_, ?team_temp) as ?team)`